# App icon sizes as of iOS 8

Tags: ios, icons

What sizes do we need to have our app icons in to support the Apple devices that will be available as of iOS 8?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

XCode 6 offers to add the following new icons for iOS 8 and later:

[image]

So, the icon sizes are 87x87, 120x120 and 180x180.

Comment: I am planning to only support iOS 8 from now. Filling in only the three icons above, I am left with a "white" icon (as in icon is missing) on iPhone 5s. What? Like I don't really get why 2x devices would use 3x icons? I mean a lot of current 2x devices (from iPhone 4s and on) can still run iOS 8 now can they not? For now I think I'll leave iOS 7.0 checked too in order to support 2x devices... weird.